# Is price of Managed VM and App Engine hosting environment the same?

Tags: google-app-engine, hosting

I'm very new to using Google cloud services. As I can see Google App Engine has two way of deployment. The first one is using App Engine sandbox and the second is managed VM.

[image]

So I'm interested in pricing. Is there any difference in price? For example if I choose managed VM instead sandbox.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pricing for the Sandbox can be found on the [App Engine Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing) page.
Pricing for the Managed VM's can be found on the [Compute Engine Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing) page:

> While in beta, pricing is based on [Compute Engine Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing) for each VM. Pricing will change in the future.

Based on the linked Price pages:

- The Minimum cost for a Sandboxed instance: $0.05 / hour (F1 class, 128MB RAM, 600MHz CPU)
- The Minimum cost for a Managed VM: $0.063 (n1-standard-1, 3.75GB RAM, 2.75[GCEU](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#gceu) CPU)

For other classes of sandbox instances see this page: [Adjusting Application Performance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings)

Before jumping to the conclusion that Managed VMs are cheaper: each app gets **28 free instance-hours per day** for Sandbox, so chances are good you won't even have to pay for any. Also with further configuration you can achieve to only pay for further "used" instance hours (e.g. you can play with `min_idle_instances` and `max_idle_instances` in your module config so additional instances only count toward instance hour billing when they are active (serving requests)).

### Notes:

Price shouldn't be the only (or most important) reason to chose one over the other. They are for different things with quite different characteristics.

- Sandbox instances are primarily for your application front-end: they can automatically scale as your traffic changes/grows. Many restrictions are enforced.
- Managed VMs are good for background operations which can be long or CPU consuming, most of the restrictions are not applied.

Answer (score 5):

In a nutshell: MVMs are for the same price about 10x more powerful.

Default GAE instances are F1: 600Mhz, 128MB, $0.05/h
Comparable MVM: 2500Mhz, 3.75GB, $0.05/h (typical use)

Answer (score 4):

It's not about price, it's about environment. You would not have SQL or root FS on GAE, you can't open ports. Your code base would be hard to migrate to another VPS. As a trade-off you get zero cost maintenance and effortless instant scaling.

Comment: I think you can have cloudsql in GAE, but I agree the environment is limited

Comment: What? I thought I can simply add e.g. PostgreSQL to my billing plan and my server will be able to talk to its database?